# How to fix type error (not a function) with $.get in JQuery

Tags: jquery

I used code from [How to manage pagination in multiple tables in grails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38624235/how-to-manage-pagination-in-multiple-tables-in-grails) (credit to Omar Yafer). I am getting the following error: TypeError: $.get is not a function. (In '$.get(linkItem.prop('href'))', '$.get' is undefined).

```
(function($) {
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $(".table-container").on('click', '.paginate a',
                function(event){
                    event.preventDefault();
                    var linkItem =$(this);
                    var target = linkItem.closest('div.table-container');
                    $.get(linkItem.prop('href'))
                        .done(function(data){
                            target.html(data);
                        }).fail(function(){
                        alert("There was an error loading the data");
                    });
                });
            });
        }) (jQuery)
```

Please note that I can't comment in the original post. Sorry.

Thank you.

Comment: `console.log(jQuery.fn.jquery, jQuery.fn.get)` and tell us what it logs

Comment: [Log] 3.3.1 -ajax,-ajax/jsonp,-ajax/load,-ajax/parseXML,-ajax/script,-ajax/var/location,-ajax/var/nonce,-ajax/var/rquery,-ajax/xhr,-manipulation/_evalUrl,-event/ajax,-effects,-effects/Tween,-effects/animatedSelector – function (e){return null==e?o.call(this):e<0?this[e+this.length]:this[e]} (transcript, line 284)

Comment: Ok, that's a very weird log.  Can you show us the jQuery include that you use?

Comment: I'm so sorry. I forgot to include JQuery in my code (I'm a beginner to this). I did it now and it's working.

Comment: I just realized that log is weird because I told you the wrong second argument.  It should have just been `jQuery.get`, not the .fn.  But that's good that you found your issue.

Comment: Just a comment.  Is it necessary to wrap that twice ?? Once with (function($) {}) (jQuery) and. once with $(document).ready(function() {});